# Inconsistent results of second derivative of inverse fourier transform

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, fourier-analysis

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I am trying to get the Green's function of a toy diffusion equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

with *Mathematica* 9. Then solve it by inverse Fourier transform:

```
u[x_, t_] := InverseFourierTransform[U[k, t], k, x]
D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]  
D[D[u[x, t], x], x] 

(* 0 *)
(* InverseFourierTransform[-k^2 U[k, t], k, x] *)
```

But can someone tell me why `Out[4]` and `Out[5]` are different? Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: I'd say it is a bug. You can see from the trace also where the different behavior is: `Trace[D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]]` vs. `Trace[D[D[u[x, t], x], x]]`  shows this: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xn0lo.png)  Mathematically speaking, both should give same result. Maple gives same result as you can see ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFj9n.png)

Comment: Thanks @Nasser for the trace info. I will contact wolfram to confirm that shortly.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks for your reply. But that u is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: I see, I had misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Guo would you care to post that as an official answer to your question, so that we can consider this issue closed and mark it as a bug for our site?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I thought it can be closed only if wolfram fix that issue.:)

Comment: This problem still persists in V10. However, just for the heck of it , instead of using the D command I used the twice derivative icon from the Classroom Assistant Palette. And I also used the once derivative icon twice. Both worked.

Comment: And what commands do those icons actually invoke?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for all your generous help. The wolfram technical support has just confirmed the issue originates from the first derivative of inverse Fourier transform. Actually `D[u[x, t], x]` should output `InverseFourierTransform[I k U[k, t], k, x]` rather than `InverseFourierTransform[-I k U[k, t], k, x]`.